# Half of link is working the other half is not IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7

If you take a look at this page with IE7; http://tinyurl.com/4gqwhtx

You wont be able to click half of the links, any body has any idea about this ?

Edit: I dont know howelse I can explain this situation some moderators are closed my last question by saying not enough information about the question.

My problem is when I put links into that white area I can not click them for some reason anybody has any idea about why ie7 does this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a lot of z-indexs being used. Maybe try manipulating the z-index of your links to see if you're positioning them behind something...

Comment: I used z-index to see if I can make them clickable but it pretty much didnt work out. The problem is div on the right hand side is not where its suppose to be, than I use right:218px;position:relative; to put it in a good place but this time it goes onto left bar than left bar stop working. how can I solve this problem anybody has any idea ?

Comment: I took care of it, by adding text-align:left; to the div.